# Evaluating a two-dimensional Recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, recurrence-relations

For $k=1,\ldots, \infty$, and $n=2,\ldots, k-1$ we define the following recurrence relation
$$ p_{1,k} = \frac{k-1}{k} p_{1,k-1}$$
$$ p_{n,k} = \frac{k-1}{k} p_{n,k-1}+\frac{1}{k^2} p_{n-1,k-1}$$
$$ p_{k,k} = \frac{1}{k^2} p_{k-1,k-1}$$
$$ p_{1,1} = 1$$

We may evaluate $p_{1,k}$ to be given by
$$ p_{1,k} = \frac{1}{k}$$

Similarly, we may evaluate $p_{2,k}$ to be given by
$$ p_{2,k} = \frac{k-1}{k^2}$$

We seek a generalised relation for $p_{n,k}$ which is defined non-recursively. Is this possible? If so, what form may this take?

Comment: I would start by asking where this came from, and also by asking if you're familiar with generating functions.

Comment: @ConMan This came from the function $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k \prod\limits_{j=1}^k\dfrac{1}{j^2}\left(j(j-1)+x\right)$.

I wished to express this as a traditional power series of the form $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n x^n$. 

I was able to deduce that $\prod\limits_{j=1}^k\dfrac{1}{j^2}\left(j(j-1)-x\right) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^k p_{n,k}x^n$.

Therefore if I can evaluate $p_{n,k}$ then I would be able to explicitly express $c_n$ as a summation of $p_{n,k}$ and $a_k$.

Comment: I see. I did some playing around with generating functions and got some results that are technically usable but they delved into some pretty gnarly territory. I'll share a bit of starting info as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to these kinds of problem is through the use of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

I'll show the start of one possible approach to find these coefficients using a generating function, but I haven't worked all the way through to determine whether it's the best approach.

First, we'll note that $p_{k, k} = \frac{1}{(k!)^2$, which we'll make use of. So overall our recursion has become:

$$\begin{eqnarray} p_{1, k} & = & 1 \\
p_{k, k} & = & \frac{1}{(k!)^2} \\
p_{j, k} & = & \frac{1}{k^2} p_{j-1, k-1} + \frac{k - 1}{k} p_{j, k-1}\ &\mbox{for } 2 \leq j \leq k - 1
\end{eqnarray}$$

So now we can define our generating function. It will be defined as:

$$A(x, y) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 1}^k p_{j, k} x^j y^k$$

We can then expand that out and apply our recursion to get something like:

$$\begin{eqnarray} A(x, y) & = & \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 1}^k p_{j, k} x^j y^k \\
& = & x y + x y^2 + \frac{1}{4} x^2 y^2 + \sum_{k = 3}^\infty \left[x y^k + \frac{1}{(k!)^2} (xy)^k + \sum_{j = 2}^{k - 1} \left(\frac{1}{k^2} p_{j - 1, k - 1} + \frac{k - 1}{k} p_{j, k - 1} \right) x^j y^k \right]
\end{eqnarray}$$

You can then break up the last term into a number of separate terms, and through some careful rearranging get some terms involving $p_{j, k} x^j y^k$ that you can hopefully transform back into a version of the original function (noting that if you see terms like $k p_{j, k} y^k$ then that's indicative of derivatives).

Some other potentially useful identities are $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty z = \frac{z}{z - 1}$ and $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k!)^2} = I_0 (2 \sqrt{z})$, where $I_0(z)$ is a [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) of the first kind.

Given the structure of the recurrence, making the generating function exponential in $y$ might be more useful, or there might be a transformation of the original recurrence that would simplify things (I played around with definitions like $q_{j, k} = \frac{k!}{(k - j)!} p_{j, k}$ and they showed a little promise).

Comment: This was really helpful thank you. I considered the following transformation $q^n_j := (n+j) p^n_{n+j}$ for $j \geq 1$. This works out a little nicer because we obtain the following relation
$$ q^{(n)}_j = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
        1 & n=1 & j \geqslant 0 \\
        & \\
        \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}q^{n-1}_{0} & n\geqslant 2 & j=0 \\
        & \\
        q^{n}_{j-1}+\dfrac{q^{n-1}_{j}}{(n+j)(n+j-1)} & n \geqslant 2 & j \geqslant 1 \\
    \end{array}
    \right.$$

This should be a much easier relation to work with,  since we have $q^n_0 = (n!(n-1)!)^{-1}$ what do you think?